# How to open local audio file in new tab and play with default player - javascript/jquery/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I need to open audio mp3 or other audio format file in new tab. File path is local system like

> file:///home/path_to_mp3/xyz.mp3

I am not uploading files on server.

Audio file should be played by default player like Windows Media Player, VLC player or whatever is installed in PC.

I tried it like this:

```
<a href="file:///home/path_to_mp3/xyz.mp3" target="_blank"> click to play </a>
```

It's working fine for MS-Word, text or other format files, but not working for audio.

I am using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Are the three slashes after the file: intentional.  Supposed to be two slashes.

Comment: While any local file path(/home/username/Desktop/xyz.mp3) put in browser address bar, it add file:// at start of the url and start play. It become - file:///home/username/Desktop/xyz.mp3